# SimplesamlPHP configuration

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I’m new to SSO and trying to set up simplesamlphp on an existing Windows, PHP/MySQL server.  I have installed the latest version of simplesamlphp, and followed the configuration instructions on the simplesaml.org site, including setting up the VirtualHost in the Apache config file, setting the basurlpath, auth.password, secretsalt and technical contact info in the simplesaml config file.  At this point, I am able to load the frontpage_federation.php page, but when I try to log in as administrator, the process times out.  I get an error message saying the site can’t be reached, and the site took too long to respond.  Has anyone experienced this before & can you give me some ideas on what mistake(s) I am making in my configuration?

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName service.example.corp:8080
        DocumentRoot G:/localhost/simplesamlphp/www/service.example.corp

        SetEnv SIMPLESAMLPHP_CONFIG_DIR G:/localhost/simplesamlphp/config

        Alias /simplesaml G:/localhost/simplesamlphp/www
        <Directory G:/localhost/simplesamlphp/www>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

config.php

```
'baseurlpath' => 'https://service.example.corp:8080/simplesaml/',
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that something goes wrong in redirecting you after you've entered credentials and that you end up on a URL without that port number. Your browser's web development toolbar, or the excellent SAML Tracer browser extension, should be able to confirm what requests are sent to what exact URLs. That will likely help to pinpoint your problem.